# Is the hypercone contractible?

Tags: general-topology

I know the cone CX is contractible but was wondering if the 3 dimensional cone in 4-space was also contractible.

Comment: What is "the 3-dimensional cone in 4-space"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to [the hypercone as described here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone) This is indeed contractible. One way to see this is that if $x,y,z,w$ satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2-w^2=0$, then so do $(tx,ty,tz,tw)$ for any $t$. So there is a homotopy of the identity map $f(x,y,z,t)=(x,y,z,t)$ on the hypercone to the constant map at $0$ given by $f_t(x,y,z,w)=(1-t)(x,y,z,w)$. This is sufficient to show contractibility.

Comment: Thanks. This is the hypercone isometrically embedded in $R^4$, right?

Comment: What would be the case for the hypercone as an intrinsic 3-surface?

Comment: Actually I shoud have said locally embedded due to the issue with the point at the tip not allowing the conical n-surface to be a smooth manifold.

Comment: This proof works for the hypercone as an intrinsic surface. The function $f$ is only defined on the hypercone itself.